# Configuring Python Environment (poetry) in Codespaces

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry, virtual-environment, codespaces

I want to select my project's python interpreter as poetry environment in Codespaces. By the way I connect codespaces with my local VSCode. I can see and select interpreter from poetry via command palette.

However it doesn't seem to work, since the imports are undefined for VSCode.

I can use poetry environment with VSCode, when I work local and start VSCode in poetry shell with the command `code .` but I can't use this, since it is a remote development environment.

In the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKV3v.png) you can clearly see, that I selected poetry as Python Interpreter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, make sure you have `django` installed in your current environment. Detailed tutorials can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django).

Then, your error is provided by **Linting**, if your code can run normally. **Linting** can be turned off in the following ways.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. search and select **Python:Enable/Disable Lingting**

   [image]
3. Choose **Disable**

   [image]